# What's the right way to execute a Twilio Studio conversation flow?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, flask-sqlalchemy, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-studio

Im learning how to set a twilio studio flow with python, I'm currently testing one of the templates that Twilio provides, and Im communicating with the bot from WhatsApp. However, I can only send the first message of the flow and if I send another message, this message pop up:

`Unable to create record: Execution XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX is already active for this contact. End the active Execution before creating a new one`

I tried to add `.update(status='ended')` to my variable, but it just kinda looped every time I sent a message, I know that every time that theres an incoming message it will trigger the conversation. So my question is, how can I continue the conversation flow without creating a new trigger every time that theres an incomming message?

Here's my flow in case it's necessary.
[image]

And this is the functions and endpoints that I'm using to trigger the action:

```
@ twilio.route('/incoming_message', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_message_data() -> str:

    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = {}
        error, message, code = False, '', ''
        message = incoming_message()
        response.update({'sucess': True, 'message': message, 'message': f'{message}', 'status_code': 200, 'error': None, 'code': f'{code}'} if message and message != [{}]else {
            'sucess': False,  'message': 'Message could not be sent', 'status_code': 400, 'error': f'{error}', 'code': f'{code}'})
        return message


def twilio_studio_flow(phone_number: str) -> str:
    '''
    Twilio Studio Flow
    '''
    response = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    execution = twilio_client.studio \
        .v2 \
        .flows(Config.TWILIO_STUDIO_FLOW_SID) \
        .executions \
        .create(to=(f'whatsapp:{phone_number}'), from_=Config.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
                parameters={
            "appointment_time": datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
        })\
        .update(status='ended')


def validate_phone_number(phone_number: str) -> bool:
    '''
    Validate phone number
    '''
    try:
        phone = phonenumbers.parse(phone_number.strip(), None)
        client = Client.query.filter_by(phone=phone_number).first()
        return phonenumbers.is_valid_number(phone) and client is not None
    except Exception:
        return False

def incoming_message() -> str:
    '''
    Receive incoming messages
    '''
    # Get the message the user sent our Twilio number
    incoming_message = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    # Get the phone number of the person sending the text message
    phone_number = request.values.get('From', None).replace('whatsapp:', '')
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    if validate_phone_number(phone_number) and incoming_message:
        resp.message(twilio_studio_flow(phone_number))

    else:
        resp.message(
            'Lo sentimos, no pudimos validar tu numero de telefono ')

    return str(resp)
```

Thanks in advance for helping me :).

As I mentioned previously, I want to know the right way to execute a Twilio Studio. Honestly, I cheked the docs but it's a little bit unclear on how to this.

Comment: From what I can tell is shouldn't be necessary to invoke the execution programatically. It seems like you want to run the flow on each incoming message, right? Which channel are you using for this SMS, WhatsApp or a Webchat?

Comment: @IObert, Im using WhatsApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer in the comments, I'd suggest to link the Studio flow directly to the WhatsApp sender in the console (instead of invoking the flow manually via the API).

To connect the Studio Flow to your WhatsApp number ("Sender"). Click on the Trigger (Start) Widget and locate the Webhook URL field in the right-hand menu. Copy that URL to your clipboard.

[image: Studio Flow]

Next, navigate to your [WhatsApp Senders](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/whatsapp/senders) in the Twilio console. Click to select the sender that you want to use with this Studio Flow. Paste the Webhook URL that you copied from your Studio Flow into the field Webhook URL for incoming messages. Don't forget to click **Update WhatsApp Sender**.

Now, any time you receive an inbound message on your selected WhatsApp-enabled sender (number), it will be routed to your new Studio Flow.

> Taken from the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/customer-support-menu#connect-your-whatsapp-sender-to-your-studio-flow).

Comment: thank you so much for your reply :), I think that would be the way to go. I have one last question. As you mentioned, the correct way to call a flow is to directly link the flow to the WhatsApp sender. However, how can I make use of the variables in the flow (considering that I want to use my info that lives in a MySQL DB). I know that manually, you would set parameters like `parameters[variable: my_value]` and then you show that variable in the sender, so how would that process work if I don't use the API? or is there a way to use both API and Flow together?

Comment: From what I see, there are three options:
1. Use the "set variable" widget and hard-code the information you would otherwise send via the http request there. (not suited for secrets like API keys)
2. Implement a Twilio Function that does this and call it from the flow by passing the sender number to it
3. Trigger the flow via the API but in this case you would need to use the "Rest API" trigger instead of "incoming message"

Comment: This little nugget of information was very useful @IObert (setting up the webhook). Many thanks